# See all of the unique IDs related to a vmware virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I want to see all of the unique IDs that are specific for a virtual machine such as:
hardware ID, CPU ID, UUID , Mac address and etc.
could anybody please help me to find these IDs??

Comment: How do you want that ? Manually or Programmatically ?

Comment: don't matter, i just want to find a way to see all of the specific IDs associated to the virtual machine or virtual appliance  with ESXi host 5.1. and want to know how can i change them?? i would really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you finding some of these. For rest of the things you have to search the doc.

Install [pyVmomi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvmomi) and run the following code.

**EDIT:** Changed the code to run on esx host. Simply run it by python .py

Now to know how this code is working. You have to learn Manged Objects. For example here we are working with the Manged Object `vm` and this object has many properties listed in the [doc](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.VirtualMachine.html). So to retrieve uuid of a vm we are invoking  `vm.config.uuid`. Regarding other details you have to go through the [VirtualMachine](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.VirtualMachine.html) object see what all properties you nedd.

```
import sys
import atexit
import time

from pyVmomi import vim, vmodl
from pyVim.connect import Disconnect
from pyVim import connect

inputs = {'esx_ip': '15.22.10.10',
          'esx_password': 'Password123',
          'esx_user': 'root',
          'vm_name': 'ubuntu',
          }


def wait_for_task(task, actionName='job', hideResult=False):
    """
     Waits and provides updates on a vSphere task
    """

    while task.info.state == vim.TaskInfo.State.running:
        time.sleep(2)

    if task.info.state == vim.TaskInfo.State.success:
        if task.info.result is not None and not hideResult:
            out = '%s completed successfully, result: %s' % (actionName, task.info.result)
            print out
        else:
            out = '%s completed successfully.' % actionName
            print out
    else:
        out = '%s did not complete successfully: %s' % (actionName, task.info.error)
        raise task.info.error
        print out

    return task.info.result


def get_obj(content, vimtype, name):
    """
     Get the vsphere object associated with a given text name
    """
    obj = None
    container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, vimtype, True)
    for c in container.view:
        if c.name == name:
            obj = c
            break
    return obj


def main():

    si = None

    try:
        print "Trying to connect ..."
        si = connect.Connect(inputs['vcenter_ip'], 443, inputs['vcenter_user'], inputs['vcenter_password'])

    except IOError, e:
        pass

    if not si:
        print "Cannot connect to specified host using specified username and password"
        sys.exit()
    print "Connected to vcenter!"
    atexit.register(Disconnect, si)

    content = si.RetrieveContent()

    # Get the VirtualMachine Object
    vm = get_obj(content, [vim.VirtualMachine], inputs['vm_name'])

    print "GuestID: ", vm.config.guestId
    print "UUID: ", vm.config.uuid
    print "Version: ", vm.config.version

    for device in vm.config.hardware.device:
        if isinstance(device, vim.vm.device.VirtualEthernetCard):
            print "MAC Address: ", device.macAddress

    #Example of changing UUID:
    new_uuid = '423ffff0-5d62-d040-248c-4538ae2c734f'
    vmconf = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
    vmconf.uuid = new_uuid
    task = vm.ReconfigVM_Task(vmconf)
    wait_for_task(task, si)
    print "Successfully changed UUID"
    print "New UUID: ", vm.config.uuid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i really appreciate Reuben,could you please explain a little about this script?? and may i ask you to help me what should i search for finding rest of them??

Comment: i have a ESXi host not a vCenter, do i have to change some commands of this script??

Comment: Similarly if you want to get the number of cpus, You can do : `print "Number of CPU: ", vm.config.hardware.numCPU` . And the property you can find here http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.VirtualHardware.html